# Why does the file size of a png24-sprite increase when adding transparent white-space?

Tags: css, png, sprite, filesize

I am creating a png24 as sprite for css background images.

Due to padding issues I have to keep a certain amount of space between the icons in the sprite.

When doing so the file size of the png increases even though no information was added... Just empty, transparent space.

Is there any workaround for this? (I have already tried png compression - smushit - but no significant improvement made...)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Empty, transparent space *is* information as well. If a PNG has an alpha channel, then every pixel consists of the informations `(r,g,b,a)` for red, green, blue and alpha components. In case of a transparent pixel the alpha is simply 0, but it's nevertheless information that is present in the file.

Answer (score 4):

Empty is still kind of data, so when you add an empty space, you add a data that tells the PNG decoder about the empty space between each graphic.

I suppose the added file size is insignificant next to making extra requests to the server.